# Use FOSUserBundle to sign up and login for different type of users

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to use `FOSUserBundle` for signing up and login of my users.
In my case I have 4 types of users (each one have different fields ): students, professors, administrator and Staff.

I have seen the documentation and from what I have seen is that I should have one class called User that extend `BaseUser`:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
```

I couldn't understand how to represent my for classes with one class User?

Thank you

Comment: You could began by creating a basic user entity to login and subscribes. Then your student, professor and administrator could be updated to inherit your basic user entity.

Comment: Do you know any example I can use it?

Comment: Did you consider using ROLES for that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use User as a parent Entity, and make other Entities professor, student, etc relate to that entity, most likely one to one relations as [described here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html).

Entity relations are easy to set up with php bin/console make-entity Professor, you can define relation as a type there.